# Using external variables from python to problog

Tags: python, variables, prolog, problog

I'm starting with problog, I want to use deeproblog for a neurosymbolic application. So I have several variables coming from python, and I want to introduce them into the problog to use them. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but more context is needed to ask your question

Comment: Not relevant anymore, I ended up using Scallopy.